# How I Disable filter MayHaveTenant when i'm using in Unit Test?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm write a unit test to validade a specific rule in a `AppServiceFile`. However in my Service, there are a filter to disable multi-tenant (`AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant`), but when I call this method by my unit-test the filter is not applied.

I'm expect to filter all entities without multi-tenancy filter.

the part of code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd3JM.png)

```
public async Task<PagedResultDto<CarteiraClienteDto>> GetTenantsWithContractsAsync(PagedCarteiraClienteRequestDto input)
 {
     CheckGetAllPermission();

     using (CurrentUnitOfWork.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MayHaveTenant))
     {
         var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input);
         var totalCount = query.Count();

         query = ApplyPaging(query, input);

         //Here the filter is applied and return all tenants
         var tenants = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

         //Here no contract is returned
         var contracts = await _contractsRepository.GetAll().AsNoTracking()
             .ToListAsync();

         //TODO: continue the code
     }

     return null;
 }
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Mistake. I'm have use a wrong filter. The correct was MustHaveTenant.